# Terminal only shows $

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-from-scratch

I tried building my own linux distribution and I follow the Linux From Scratch book. When I tried entering the following commands in bashrc.

```
set +h

umask 022

LFS=/mnt/lfs

LC_ALL=POSIX

PATH=/tools/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

export LFS LC_ALL PATH
```

After this when I restart the terminal. I am seeing only $ symbol. I thought that entry I made in bashrc is the problem. So, I reverted back it and restarted the system too. But, still am seeing the same problem. Also, the auto completion too not working. Please, help me to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, I got my terminal back by reinstalling bash shell by executing the following command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow
You should set the 'PS1' variable. Search it
This is my PS1, for example:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

Comment: Thank you Behrooz for the reply.